# Remove Author, Post and Category-related Text from a Theme?

Tags: theme-twenty-ten

How do I remove?

- "Author Archives: Merms", on http://shs.merms.info/author/Merms.
- "by Merms", but keep "Posted on December 30, 2010" on all pages
- Posted in Article, Awards, Employer News, Events, Resources, Uncategorized and keep "Comments" on all pages.

Using twenty twenty ten modified. Not using sidebar widget.

Comment: search for these strings in the template files, then create a child theme in which you copy these files and remove the strings...

Answer (score 1):

In functions.php find:

```
 if ( ! function_exists( 'twentyten_posted_on' ) ) :
/**
 * Prints HTML with meta information for the current post—date/time and author.
 *
 * @since Twenty Ten 1.0
 */
function twentyten_posted_on() {
    printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Posted on</span> %2$s <span class="meta-sep">by</span> %3$s', 'twentyten' ),
        'meta-prep meta-prep-author',
        sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><span class="entry-date">%3$s</span></a>',
            get_permalink(),
            esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
            get_the_date()
            ),
        sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%3$s</a></span>',
            get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ),
            sprintf( esc_attr__( 'View all posts by %s', 'twentyten' ), get_the_author() ),
            get_the_author()
        )
    );
}
endif;
```

Change to:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'twentyten_posted_on' ) ) :
/**
 * Prints HTML with meta information for the current post—date/time and author.
 *
 * @since Twenty Ten 1.0
 */
function twentyten_posted_on() {
    printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Posted on</span> %2$s <span class="meta-sep">by</span> %3$s', 'twentyten' ),
        'meta-prep meta-prep-author',
        sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><span class="entry-date">%3$s</span></a>',
            get_permalink(),
            esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
            get_the_date()
        ),

    );
}
endif;
```

In other words you're just removing the bit of code that reads:

```
sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%3$s</a></span>',
                get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ),
                sprintf( esc_attr__( 'View all posts by %s', 'twentyten' ), get_the_author() ),
                get_the_author()
            )
```

Comment: That's for the author, just noticed the second part of your question. Right below the above function is the twentyten_posted_in() function. just go to the single.php file and remove the call to the twentyten_posted_in() function to remove the posted in section. The call is towards the bottom of the file.

Comment: Hi Adam - 

Thank you for your help. Let me know if I can help you with anything. Everything ended up working out and I was able to keep the authors, which at first was causing layout issues that was why I wanted to remove it. 

Dave

Comment: Hi Im afraid I got an error message when I did this, luckily had saved a copy of functions.php before I did it.